# Select function that references a condition in a table SQL

Tags: sql, select

I am looking to find all names (`PName`) in a table that have ages(`PAge`) greater than the age of the person who has the `PID` of 3.

So far I have:

```
SELECT PName
FROM Person
WHERE PAge >= [PAge].[PID].[3]
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: And is PID in the table Person? or In a table PAge?

Answer (score 3):

You cant reference a second row in that way, at least not in standard sql.

Use

```
SELECT PName FROM Person WHERE PAge >= (select PAge from Person where PID=3)
```